# Can back up specific files automatically from FTP to a specific folder using PHP?

Tags: php, ftp, backup

I have lots of backup files in my FTP.
The file name like : `index.php.bk-2013-12-27`

I want to back up those files to the folder named `/backup/`

so inside of my httpdocs folder looks like this.

- index.php
- backup/index.php.bk.2013-12-27

the following both methods are fine to done this.

**01.** if any file contain name **.bk** that should be backed up automatically to the folder `backup`

or

**02.**

- create a text file named `backup_move.text` that file contains the
  paths of files that need to be copied and placed it into the httpdocs folder.
- then the php script extract those file path from the
  `backup_move.text` and sync the files to the folder named `backup`

How can I do this with some php coding.?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You will most likely need a cron job to accomplish scheduling of your script.

Comment: yeah I know that. first, I am looking for coding to solution 01 and 02.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done (Both solutions).

But you need to tell if the solution (01) need to be recursive or Not. I suppose you know php has got a "time" to run (standard are 60 seconds), so you know that the file you need to backup cannot require more then 55 seconds to get a backup.

You can try and use the next link, it will backup completly a site, db and file and put it into a zip file. It need to be configured a little, but it can help.

http://www.starkinfotech.com/php-script-to-take-a-backup-of-your-site-and-database/

Comment: wooohh.. how quick you've responded. thanks a lot. yeah solution (01) need to be recursive. better if it is run every day morning.

Comment: As Wp already stated. To launch it each day you need a cron job, that's another thing. This aside, how many file you need to backup? How long they are?

Comment: files almost 150 above. but each files are just below 50 kb.

Comment: Replyed into my answer.

Comment: thanks... but I am not expert in php. also no need to backup whole site. just need to back up the file named like `index.bk.2013-12-27` and `index.bk.2013-3-27`and that script says that will save the files as zip. but I need to back up that file as it is in the FTP. so ideas?

Comment: something like: <?php
$file = 'index.php';
$newfile = 'backup/index.php.bk.2013-12-27';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>